# Objective-C: How do you declare and retain an int?

Tags: objective-c, int

Here's my code:

```
@interface Game : Layer // this is from cocos2d
{
   int maxSprites;
}

@implementation Game
-(void)initVariables
{
  maxSprites = 18;
}
```

Later on, when I print it out,

```
 NSLog(@" maxSprites = %d  ", maxSprites);
```

I get:

```
 maxSprites = 2
```

And operations that require it to be 18, crash or don't work, as if it's really just 2 now.

How would that be possible? =)

<kbd>APPLE</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> reveals no other usage of the `maxSprites` variable.

I've looked at other code examples and often they're exposing the variable with a getter and setter, and they are also using `@property`.  Am I missing something?  I'm new to Objective-C, so I might as well just be!

EDIT:
hrmph, why'd I get a -1?

Thanks, I will try to learn how to do a Watchpoint.

Until then, I would like to say that I did a <kbd>APPLE</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for maxSprites" In Project, Textual, Contains, Ignore Case and only resulted in:

```
Game.h:     int maxSprites;
Game.m:     maxSprites = 18;
Game.m:     NSLog(@" maxSprites  = %d", maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@" maxSprites  = %d", maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@"maxSprites is at %p", &maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@"maxSprites is at %p", &maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@" maxSprites  = %d", maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@" maxSprites  = %d", maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@"maxSprites is at %p", &maxSprites);
Game.m:     NSLog(@"maxSprites is at %p", &maxSprites);
```

2nd EDIT:

I found the location where it changes using a watchpoint.  It changes here:

```
Expression: “*(int *) 67379960”
New Value: 2
Old  Value: 18
```

On this line:

```
[self checkMatchBarAward:spriteTypeToAdd];
```

Odd? That function doesn't do anything with `maxSprites`.

EDIT:
-I'm going to make a new question now to find out why the value is changing on its own.  Thank you for your help guys, great job.

New post will be taken up here:
[Objective-C: int value changing without cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941686/objective-c-int-value-changing-without-cause)

Comment: May we see that method (or some reduced version of it that still creates the same error)?

Comment: Hi Chuck, I'd like to give NSD the "answer" and green flagged him.  I continue this problem in another thread here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941686/objective-c-int-value-changing-without-cause

Comment: since he satisfied the original question : "How do you declare and retain an int?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't retain an int because it's not an object. Use a watchpoint and find out when your variable is changing.

Comment: I got this problem and can't watch =(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598444/iphone-xcode-3-1-4-3-1-2-sdk-watchpoints-dont-work

Comment: ok, found it.  I used the simulator instead of device.  and I get :
Expression: “*(int *) 67379960”
New Value: 2
Old  Value: 18

on this line:
 [self checkMatchBarAward:spriteTypeToAdd];

odd?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that initVariables is called at all?
Is the value always 2?
Are you refering to the same variable called maxSprites?
Try:

```
NSLog(@"maxSprites is at %p", &maxSprites);
```

It's hard to believe that the content of a variable just changes.

Edit:
First I thought it could be "garbage" from the stack, but then
I realized, that, of course, Objective-C objects are not stored on the stack,
but the heap. And the MacOS X malloc implementation "blanks" allocated memory with 0.

Comment: Thank you sir for the address printing, I totally forgot about using that in Objective-C.  I'm more of a C guy.  I sampled it at 3 intervals.  here are the results:

       maxSprites  = 18
       maxSprites is at 0x8174f8

       maxSprites  = 18
       maxSprites is at 0x8174f8

       maxSprites  = 2
       maxSprites is at 0x8174f8


initVariables is called twice.

It must be a grievous coding error on my part that I will laugh at terribly after I figure it out..  =)

I will have to do watchpoint thang now.